# Wrong xml path or just me?

Tags: xml, apache, path

I have a PHP script that loads in an XML file.  That said XML file exists in the same directory as the script - the path in the script for the XML file is relative to the php file.

Now when I put that PHP script and XML files in the root of my website it works, yet when I put that PHP script and XML files in a sub-directory, the XML file doesn't load!  The script is running, but the XML doesn't get loaded in.

I'm running Apache if that helps?

```
/root
    - rssfeed.php
    - rss.xml
```

Works!

```
/root/rss/
    - rssfeed.php
    - rss.xml
```

Doesn't work!

Comment: Have you checked the ownership/permissions on the sub folder? Are you including the trailing slash in the path before appending the XML file name?

Comment: Do I really need the trailing slash even if the xml file is in the same directory as the called PHP script?

Comment: Don't know how you load the XML-file: like this: `fopen("rss.xml", "r");`? Then try: `fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "rss.xml", "r");`